# Modified Transportation Problem

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, linear-programming, optimal-transport

Could you point me to some article that tackles a problem similar to this.

There are two sets:

- Sources $A = a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$
- Destinations $B = b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n$

The distance between source $a_i$ and destination $b_j$ is $c_{i,j}$

The capacity of each destination is $k >=1$

There are two constraints:

- Each destination $b_j$ needs to be connected to exactly $k$ sources
- Each source $a_i$ needs to be connected to exactly $k$ destinations

The goal is to find the transference plan that minimizes the cost while fulfilling the constraints

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will end up with a MIP (Mixed Integer Program). I assume here you actually have a demand of $k$ at each destination node (capacities are typically for source nodes; of course I may just be misreading your problem). A MIP model could look like:

$$\begin{align}
   \min & \sum c_{i,j} x_{i,j} \\
        & \varepsilon \cdot y_{i,j} \le x_{i,j} \le M \cdot y_{i,j} \\
        & \sum_j x_{i,j} \ge k \>\> \forall i \\
        & \sum_i y_{i,j} = k \>\> \forall j \\
        & \sum_j y_{i,j} = k \>\> \forall i \\
        & x_{i,j} \ge 0 \>\text{(flow variables)} \\
        & y_{i,j} \in \{0,1\} \> \text{(arc is used)}
\end{align}$$

$\varepsilon$ and $M$ are a small and a large number. $\varepsilon$ is the minimum flow when an arc is turned on (e.g. $\varepsilon=0.001$). $M$ is an upper bound on the flow on an arc (i.e. arc capacity).